How to fix "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (192,) and (1,)" error?
I can't figure out why the shape of y is (1,). I thought since the return of my function is being calculated with the same thing I'm plotting on the x axis that they would have the same shape. Any tips on how I can fix this?
When I run the code without the function definition, it plots exactly what I'm looking for. However, once I throw everything I'll need for my cw signals into a function then I run into this problem even though I haven't change anything else.
def cw_signal (amp, f, t, phi):
    seconds_per_day = 24*60*60
    amp = 2e-6
    f = 3e-9
    phi = math.pi / 2
    t = np.linspace(53005, 58849, 192)
    return amp*np.cos(2*np.pi*f * seconds_per_day*t +phi)

residuals = np.zeros(192)
wn = 1e-6
residuals += wn*np.random.randn(192)
t = np.linspace(53005, 58849, 192)

plt.plot(t, cw_signal, marker='.', ls='', label='cw')
plt.errorbar(t, cw_signal+residuals, marker='.', yerr = wn, ls='', label='cw+residuals')
plt.xlabel('MJD')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()


You need to actually call the function cw_signal to use it. You also seem to have hardcoded the parameters into the function rather than taking the arguments from the function call.
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cw_signal (amp, f, t, phi):
    seconds_per_day = 24*60*60
    return amp*np.cos(2*np.pi*f * seconds_per_day*t +phi)

# the arguments are now outside the function and used to call the function
amp = 2e-6
f = 3e-9
phi = math.pi / 2
t = np.linspace(53005, 58849, 192)

signal_result = cw_signal(amp, f, t, phi)

residuals = np.zeros(len(t))
wn = 1e-6
residuals += wn*np.random.randn(len(t))

plt.plot(t, signal_result, marker='.', ls='', label='cw')
plt.errorbar(t, signal_result+residuals, marker='.', yerr = wn, ls='', label='cw+residuals')
plt.xlabel('MJD')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

Result:

